# How to make text go below a table in HTML?

Tags: html

So i wanted to make the **Growing Up** go below the table, but it appeared at the right side of the table.
I already put br tag at the end of the table tag as below:

```html
<table height="300px" cellpadding="8" border="1" align="left">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <b>Name:</b>
    </td>
    <td>
      AHMAD ASHREEFUL AMNI BIN ABDUL RAZAK<br>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <b>Interests: </b>
    </td>
    <td>
      Technology, cars, sports<br>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table><br>
<p>
  <h2>Growing Up</h2>
</p>
```

Any help?

Comment: remove the ```align="left"``` attribute and it'll work as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this answer can help you, btw you just delete align object.
the text inside the table automatically has a left alignment if you're not set them.

please read this article if you want to check align more detail [w3school here](http://www-db.deis.unibo.it/courses/TW/DOCS/w3schools/tags/att_object_align.asp.html)

or if you want to text inside table, you can set by using the style in a table cell or table row

`<td>` -> `<td style="text-align: left">`

or

`<tr>` -> `<tr style="text-align: left">`

and its your code, I just delete the align mark.

```html
<table height="300px" cellpadding="8" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <b>Name:</b>
    </td>
    <td>
      AHMAD ASHREEFUL AMNI BIN ABDUL RAZAK<br>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <b>Interests: </b>
    </td>
    <td>
      Technology, cars, sports<br>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table><br>
<p>
  <h2>Growing Up</h2>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try wrapping the table and the paragraph elements in separate 's. In the paragraph  add the style="clear:both".

```
<div>
    <table height="300px" cellpadding="8" border="1" align="left">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <b>Name:</b>
            </td>
            <td>
                AHMAD ASHREEFUL AMNI BIN ABDUL RAZAK<br>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <b>Interests: </b>
            </td>
            <td>
                Technology, cars, sports<br>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</div>



<div style="clear:both">
    <p>
    <h2>Growing Up</h2>
    </p>
</div>
```